# Doing away with Runtime Error(SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++

I don't think in my code I tried accessing null pointers, or initialising large arrays, someone help please, I dunno where the Runtime Error(SIGSEGV) is coming from. Question to problem can be found at https://www.codechef.com
/MARCH18B/problems/MINEAT

edit:
I think i found out, NathanOliver was right, v1, because of my code, happens to be sometimes empty. Some answers were actually found out of my loop (above n). Thanks alot. I fixed that and I finally got AC, but just 30 points, my code took an additional 0.01 seconds to run. Can anyone help me optimize it, based on Problem statement, Please.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t; cin>>t; while(t--)
    {
        int n = 0, h = 0; cin>>n>>h;

        vector<int> v; vector<int> v1;

        for(int i = 0; i != n; i++){int a; cin>>a; v.push_back(a);}

        for(int j = 1; j <= h; j++)
        {
            int hold = 0;

            for(auto k : v)
            {
                if (j >= k){hold +=1;}

                else if (j < k){if(k % j == 0){hold += (k/j);} else{hold += ((k/j)+1);}}
            }

            if (hold <= h){v1.push_back(j);}
        }
        cout<<*min_element(v1.begin(),v1.end())<<endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `v1` has a non zero size?

Comment: Have you used a debugger or valgrind?  They'll tell you the specific line that's segfaulting.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the min_element function's return value? According to the user input, min_element function returns an iterator to 'last element' which is basically a nullptr. Since you're dereferencing it directly, you get the error.

Comment: thought end() refers to one element past the last, and not the last element itself?

Comment: According to this[link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) min_element returns last if the range is empty. The last element is an invalid pointer. So directly dereferencing it causes this error.

Comment: according to problem statement, what should i do if range is empty

Comment: I'd check if the user input is valid. In the code you post, user can enter, for example, the negative length.